# in Tkinter is there a way to get the geometrymanager information from a widget that it slaves

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to get the geometry manager and options from a widget
for example:

```
f=Frame(root)
f.place(x=100,y=100,height=100,width=100)
```

i want to get the geometrymanager(place in this example) and its options (x,y,height,width) so i can reimplement the widget in another parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every widget has a method named `winfo_manager` which will return the name of the geometry manager that is controlling it:

```
f.winfo_manager()
```

In your case, it would return the string `"place"`.

Each widget also has a method for getting the parameters of the geometry manager. In the case of `place` it is `place_info`. This will return a dictionary with all of the options used by the widget:

```
f.place_info()
```

In your case it would return a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
{   
    'anchor': 'nw',
    'bordermode': 'inside',
    'height': '100',
    'in': <tkinter.Tk object .>,
    'relheight': '',
    'relwidth': '',
    'relx': '0',
    'rely': '0',
    'width': '100',
    'x': '100',
    'y': '100'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
f.winfo_geometry()
```

From docs:

> Return geometry string for this widget in the form "widthxheight+X+Y".

Or combine `f.winfo_width()`, `f.winfo_height()`, `f.winfo_x()` and `f.winfo_y()` calls.