# In tinker 3.x How to find out if parent is using pack, grid or place?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, layout

In a custom tkinter 3.x  control
How can you find out if the parent invoking the control is using pack grid or place?
In order to handle the correct style of layout positioning.

I am setting a global variable to test with ie: usingPack = 1

I would like usingPack = whatLayout( parent )

Comment: In pure `tkinter` you have `parent.winfo_manager()` docs are [here](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/winfo+manager). Try calling that. It probably will work even with custom tkinter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in Tkinter is there a way to get the geometrymanager information from a widget that it slaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425207/in-tkinter-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-geometrymanager-information-from-a-widget-t)